# mathjax overlapping in <a> element

Tags: css, mathjax

I want to write some basic mathematical formulas which I handle using mathjax as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body a {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2px 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px; 
    height:36px;
    width: 36px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<a title="\sqrt{a}">
$\sqrt{a}$</a>
<a title="\frac ab">
$\frac ab$</a>
<a title="\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}">
$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}$</a>


</body>
</html>
```

The problem is the overlapping of big formulas. You can see the demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ev6wf0rd/

Is there a way to configure Mathjax to avoid this problem?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 2):

You could either :

- Increase the `a` element size, like [here (I modified your jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/fqzpecs1/)
- Remove size contraints so it's default to `auto` : [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fqzpecs1/2/)
- Decrease size of MathJax items for the elements that overlap [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/fqzpecs1/5/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to increase the `a` element size! I want it to have `36px` size not more. So I thought maybe we could configure Mathjax instead of the size of element.

Comment: Ok sorry I misinterpreted the question ! I added a 3rd solution, which uses the `zoom` css property (or scale for firefox-like browsers)

Comment: This is fine. However I am looking for a better solution. I can also use `style="font-size: 9px"` in the elements that overlap. But I was wondering if there is a solution to configure Mathjax in a way Mathjax has font scale based on width of its container.

Comment: @mac There is no built-in functionality for that in MathJax right now.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger : Okay.Thanks.